# `::before` and `::after` pseudoelements do not work in the stylesheet

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome, pseudo-element

I want to add a Font Awesome icon via CSS. I have already linked the stylesheets of the fonts and my `style.css`.

I don’t understand why when I refresh the page the icon doesn’t appear. Despite stating the font family, font weight and proper Unicode.

```css
hr.camera {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 5px solid #f44336;
  max-width: 60%;
  margin: 2em auto;
}

hr.camera::after {
  content: '\f030';
  font-family: "Font Awsome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <h2>My Icon</h2>
    <hr class="camera">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you loaded the actual font anywhere?

Comment: _“I have already linked the stylesheets of the fonts and my `style.css`.”_ — How exactly have you done that? Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors, including CSS errors. The dev tools provide an **Inspector** / **Elements** and a **Network** tab. Inspect your elements. What do the applied CSS rules reveal? Please confirm: Are the resources _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested? Amend the URL accordingly.

Comment: @slow Thank you so much, I added a <span> and finally I can see the icon.

Comment: @GiosueCongiu nice! Added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the `<hr />` to a `<span></span>` then it should do the work.

```
<span class="camera"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Awesome spelling is wrong.
font-family: `"Font Awsome 5 Free";` change it to `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";`

Comment: Hi, thanks for it but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.